# Jib-Maven-plugin with Jenkins scripted pipeline: how to log in to private docker registry?

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins-pipeline, jhipster, jib

Regarding [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59254492/7773582), I updated my JHipster-Application with scripted Jenkins pipeline and have now in `Jenkinsfile` (partly following [these hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562224/how-do-i-pass-jenkins-credentials-to-gradle)):

```
[...]

 def dockerImage
    withEnv(["DOCKER_CREDS=credentials('myregistry-login')"]) {
        stage('publish docker') {
            sh "./mvnw -X -ntp jib:build"
        }
    }
```

with Jenkins global credentials `myregistry-login` saved in my Jenkins-Server to my own docker registry v2 docker-container `https://myregistry.mydomain.com` (domain changed for security reasons). I can successfully do a `$ docker login myregistry.mydomain.com` (as well as `docker login https://myregistry.mydomain.com` as well as `docker login myregistry.mydomain.com:443`) from local bash with the user and password stored in `myregistry-login`.

In `pom.xml` (following [these hints](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables) as well as [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials), [this](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#system-properties) and [this](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-maven-plugin/README.md)):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <to>
      <image>myregistry.mydomain.com:443/username/imagename</image>
      <tags>
        <tag>${maven.build.timestamp}</tag>
        <tag>latest</tag>
      </tags>
      <auth>
        <username>${env.DOCKER_CREDS_USR}</username>
        <password>${env.DOCKER_CREDS_PSW}</password>
      </auth>
    </to>
    <container>
      <jvmFlags>
        <jvmFlag>-Xms512m</jvmFlag>
        <jvmFlag>-Xmx1G</jvmFlag>
        <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
      </jvmFlags>
      <mainClass>de.myproject_name.MyApp</mainClass>
    </container>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

where `username`, `imagename` and `de.myproject_name.MyApp` are placeholders here.

Unfortunately I get

```
[DEBUG] TIMING  Retrieving registry credentials for myregistry.mydomain.com:443
[DEBUG] No credentials could be retrieved for registry myregistry.mydomain.com:443
[...]
[ERROR] I/O error for image [myregistry.mydomain.com:443/username/imagename]:
[ERROR]     Connect to myregistry.mydomain.com:443 [myregistry.mydomain.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
[DEBUG] TIMED   Authenticating push to myregistry.mydomain.com:443 : 460.0 ms
[DEBUG] TIMED   Building and pushing image : 514.0 ms
[ERROR] I/O error for image [registry-1.docker.io/library/adoptopenjdk]:
[ERROR]     Socket closed
```

So the `withEnv` isn't forwarded to Maven and/or the jib-maven-plugin is not reading the `<auth>`-Tag, right? What am I still doing wrong?
And why is there an I/O error to `registry-1.docker.io`?

Comment: Even before attempting to run `mvn`, I would first do `echo "user=$DOCKER_CREDS_USR pass=$DOCKER_CREDS_PSW"` to see if they are really defined. I don't think they are defined. And I'd also do `curl -v registry-1.docker.io/library/adoptopenjdk`. It almost seems like the Jenkins server doesn't allow the connection.

Comment: And I'd also run the `mvn` command on my local machine to verify at least it works when the variables are properly defined.

Comment: And I'd also try passing concrete wrong credentials, e.g., `<username>wrong</username><password>wrong</password>` in `pom.xml` to see if the message `No credentials could be retrieved for registry` goes away. This will rule out misconfiguration in Jib.

Comment: @ChanseokOh - if I try your suggested `echo`, I get `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: DOCKER_CREDS_USR for class: groovy.lang.Binding`. So how can I pass values from Jenkins global credentials to Maven correctly? I read all the links above and of course some more but no luck. Also I tried to `curl -v  https://myregistry.myserver.com:443` and both, my server and the official server give the same results, which seem to be o.k - although I don't know, why registry-1.docker.io is used in second instance.

Comment: @ChanseokOh - if I try `mvn` locally, I can't test the credentials from my Jenkins server. But `./mvnw -X -ntp jib:build` locally pushes the image (with given tags) successfully to my private dockerregistry. Maven then uses my `.docker/config.json`, because if I delete this file, it fails with `401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that `${env.DOCKER_CREDS_USR}` is empty or undefined. And it is empty if the environment variables are not defined where Maven runs. Testing `<username>wronguser</username><password>foo</password>` and checking the log will confirm this. And as for why the variable is not defined, sorry, I don't know much about Jenkins.

Comment: Oh, and although I virtually know nothing about Jenkins, after reading one of the Jenkins docs you linked, I think it should either be `echo "user=${env.DOCKER_CREDS_USR}"` or `sh "echo $DOCKER_CREDS_USR"`. That is, if you want to directly reference an environment variable inside the Jenkins file, you should access it through `env.XXX`. OTOH, if you run an actual `echo` binary through a shell, you would directly access it with `$DOCKER_CREDS_USR`, I think. Try both approaches to see if they are defined in both cases.

Comment: Oh, actually, my guess wasn't entirely correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40718201/1701388

Comment: Also take a look at https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/

Comment: @ChanseokOh - thanks for your tipps. `sh "echo $DOCKER_CREDS_USR"` gives me `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` again. But `sh "echo \"user=${env.DOCKER_CREDS_USR}\"";` results in Jenkins output: `+ echo user=null
user=null` - so, this is the right syntax. But the variables aren't set. https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/ uses declarative pipeline (not scripted) and in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40718201/1701388 the answer ends in the same problem (see Sebastian Woinar's comment to the answer).

Comment: Cool. At least it is clear that the variables are not set at the beginning. My hunch is that `DOCKER_CREDS` is set as literal `credentials...`, not `DOCKER_CREDS_USR` and such. Try `echo ${env.DOCKER_CREDS}`. And for checking environment variables inside a shell (i.e., not Groovy variables within the Jenkinsfile script), use `sh "printenv"` to list all variables. By using `env.XXX`, you are accessing Groovy variables. (But coincidentally, inside Maven, you should also use `env.XXX` to read environment variables.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205758/discussion-between-chanseok-oh-and-j-gebsattel).

Answer (score 3):

Finally I've got it working.

In `Jenkinsfile` I edit the JHipster generated code to:

```
    def dockerImage
    stage('publish docker') {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'myregistry-login', passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_REGISTRY_PWD', usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER')]) {
            sh "./mvnw -ntp jib:build"        }
    }
```

In `pom.xml` I put the jib-maven-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <from>
      <image>adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot</image>
    </from>
    <to>
      <auth>
        <username>${DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER}</username>
         <password>${DOCKER_REGISTRY_PWD}</password>
       </auth>
       <image>myregistry.mydomain.com/myuser/my_image</image>
       <tags>
         <tag>${maven.build.timestamp}</tag>
         <tag>latest</tag>
       </tags>
     </to>
   <container>
     <jvmFlags>
       <jvmFlag>-Xms512m</jvmFlag>
       <jvmFlag>-Xmx1G</jvmFlag>
       <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
     </jvmFlags>
     <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyApp</mainClass>
     <entrypoint>
       <shell>bash</shell>
       <option>-c</option>
       <arg>chmod +x /entrypoint.sh &amp;&amp; sync &amp;&amp; /entrypoint.sh</arg>
     </entrypoint>
     <ports>
       <port>8080</port>
     </ports>
     <environment>
       <SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>ALWAYS</SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED>
       <JHIPSTER_SLEEP>0</JHIPSTER_SLEEP>
     </environment>
     <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
   </container>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In my remote server setup my own `docker registry v2` is running as a docker-container published via `nginx-proxy` with `letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion`. On the same custom network bridge runs my own `jenkins` server as another docker-container.

Some tests showed me that the container-name of the docker registry can not be named with the public DNS name of the registry (e.g. 'myregistry.mydomain.com' as container name). The `jenkins` docker-container gets the `embedded docker dns server` into `resolv.conf`, and docker will resolve the container-names of containers in the same network to the internal bridge-network IPs of these containers (only in case of custom docker networks).

I guess jib has to connect via ssl to push the docker image to the `docker registry` container and ssl has to be handled before the container with `nginx-proxy`, so the external address of the `docker registry` domain has to be used.

Also the docker hosts firewall has to be configured (according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57502873/7773582)) to allow traffic from the docker container `jenkins` through to the docker host. At the host it then goes back again to `docker registry` via `nginx-proxy` with ssl, right? In my case, this comes down to:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --info-zone=public
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp6s0
  sources: 
  [...] 
  rich rules: 
    rule family="ipv4" source address="172.26.0.13/32" accept
```